# iOS app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm including the full project so nothing is ambiguous.

A.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject
-(void) zero;
@end
```

A.m

```
#import "A.h"

@implementation A

#define width 3
#define height 3

uint8_t** _board;

-(void) zero
{
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        _board[i][j] = 0;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    free(_board[i]);
free(_board);
}

-(id) init
{
self = [super init];
if(self)
{
    _board = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t*)*width);
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        _board[i] = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*height);
}
return self;
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "A.h"

@implementation ViewController

A* _gameBoard;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_gameBoard = [[A alloc] init];
[[A alloc] init];

[_gameBoard zero];
}

@end
```

Specifically, the program crashes in the function zero when setting _board.  I would also like to point out that if you remove

```
[[A alloc] init];
```

from ViewController's implementation, the program doesn't crash.  Thanks for any help, in advance.

Comment: `_gameBoard = [[A alloc] init];
[[A alloc] init];` it's strange to alloc-init two times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. First of all, it doesn't make sense to create another `A` instance and not assign it to a variable.

The main problem though is that you're not using instance variables (or properties) neither on your `ViewController` (`_gameBoard`) nor on `A` (`uint8_t** _board`).

Making them instance variables (or properties) should fix your issue.

PS: You may want to use `NSArray` instead of C-style arrays also.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was I didn't know putting _board in the place I was caused it to be static.  I thought it was an instance variable all along.  Guess I just didn't know the syntax.  Anyway, thanks a lot, this problem has been hell for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make `board` an ivar of class A and your problem should go away.  Right now it is a global, and the second `[[A alloc] init];` is `free`ing it (it appears you are ARC enabled, and llvm will see that the object is not actually being used and frees it immediately).

When you invoke

`[_gameBoard zero];`

it is now trying to reference the `free`'d global `board`, which throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Globals like `board` generally are a Bad Idea, as you have discovered.

Comment: Looks like Marcelo Fabri beat you to it.  You are absolutely right, I need to create instance variables.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No matter, as long as you get it fixed, and understand why it wasn't working.